Backdrop Blur Not Working for Nested Drop-Down Menu in Tailwind CSS
I'm working on a navigation bar using Tailwind CSS in my Next.js project, and I've implemented a drop-down menu with a nested structure. However, I'm having trouble getting the backdrop-blur effect to apply correctly to the nested menu items.
HTML
"use client";

import { Menu, type MenuProps } from "@mantine/core";
import Link from "next/link";
import { FC, Fragment } from "react";

import { INavigation } from "./DesktopHeader";
import HeaderMenuSubDropDown from "./HeaderMenuSubDropDown";

import VerifiedBadgeIcon from "@/components/icons/VerifiedBadgeIcon";

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

export type IHeaderMenuDropDownProps = MenuProps & {
  navigation?: INavigation;
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

const HeaderMenuDropDown: FC<IHeaderMenuDropDownProps> = (props) => {
  const { navigation, classNames, ...other } = props;

  if (!navigation) return;

  return (
    <Menu
      trigger="hover"
      zIndex={99999}
      position="bottom-start"
      classNames={{
        dropdown: "bg-transparent border-none",
        ...classNames,
      }}
      offset={0}
      {...other}
    >
      <Menu.Target>
        {navigation.url ? (
          <Link
            className="cursor-pointer hover:text-secondary-900"
            href={navigation.url}
            target={navigation.target}
          >
            {navigation?.name}
          </Link>
        ) : (
          <span className="cursor-default">{navigation?.name}</span>
        )}
      </Menu.Target>

      <Menu.Dropdown>
        {navigation?.links &&
          navigation.links.length > 0 &&
          navigation.links[0].name && (
            <div className="fixed top-14 w-fit min-w-[310px] pt-7">
              <div className="custom-backdrop relative w-full rounded-[15px] border border-black-50 bg-white/10 px-px py-2 backdrop-blur-lg">
                <ul className="w-full space-y-[1px]">
                  {navigation.links.map((link, idx) => (
                    <Fragment key={idx}>
                      {link?.subLinks && link.subLinks.length > 0 ? (
                        <div className="relative">
                          <HeaderMenuSubDropDown navigationLinks={link} />
                        </div>
                      ) : (
                        <>
                          <li className="group relative flex items-center px-6 py-3">
                            <div className="mr-[15px] size-5">
                              <VerifiedBadgeIcon />
                            </div>
                            <p className="relative text-white hover:text-secondary-900">
                              parent
                              <div className="absolute left-[260px] top-0 z-50 hidden w-full min-w-[310px] rounded-[15px] border border-black-50 px-px py-2 backdrop-blur-lg group-hover:block">
                                <li className="outer custom-backdrop relative">
                                  <div className="relative flex items-center px-6 py-3">
                                    child
                                  </div>
                                </li>
                              </div>
                            </p>
                          </li>
                        </>
                      )}
                    </Fragment>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
      </Menu.Dropdown>
    </Menu>
  );
};

export default HeaderMenuDropDown;


I am using the backdrop-blur-lg class for both the main drop-down and the nested drop-down menus. The parent menu has the class group, and I'm using group-hover:block to display the nested menu on hover.
Problem: The backdrop-blur effect is not visible on the nested menu items, and I suspect it might be due to the positioning of the elements or the stacking context. I have tried adjusting the z-index and ensuring that the parent elements have the correct styles applied, but nothing seems to work.
What I’ve Tried:
Adjusting the z-index for both the navigation bar and the drop-down menus.
Using different Tailwind CSS classes for the background to see if that makes a difference.
Testing the structure without the nested menus to ensure that the backdrop-blur effect works as expected on the main drop-down.
Questions:
How can I ensure that the backdrop-blur effect applies to the nested menu items?
Are there any specific CSS or Tailwind configuration settings that I might be missing?
Could the structure of my HTML be causing the issue, and if so, how should I refactor it?
